# method file returnsMethod Illuminate\Http\Response::file does not exist

Tags: api, laravel-5, file-upload, postman, laravel-5.6

i am trying to send a file with my API response to postman

```
        return response($company)->file($company->logo, $company->main_photo);
```

laravel woops returns:

```
Method Illuminate\Http\Response::file does not exist.
```

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you do not need to retrieve a file using the `response` helper method.

it just needs to send file location to the front-end, e.g. let assume your `$company` object shape is something like:

```
{
    id: 1234,
    name: 'My Company',
    logo: 'images/companies/logo/1425.jpg'
}
```

then it is enough to pass above object to your front-end and in a contract ask your front end to put `http://example.com/files/` at the beginning of file address then or you may define a `JsonResource` class and override the logo path with the absolute address (append base-URL to the beginning).

it might look like:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ComapnyResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($request)
    {
        return [
                'id' => $this->id,
                'name' => $this->name,
                'logo' => 'https://example.com/file/' . $this->logo,
        ];
    }
}
```

Take a look the [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-resources).

Comment: I think you should have answered why that goes wrong too.